# Git: Everytime I rebase & merge it says my branch & origin have diverged?

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, git-flow

For example:

If I do the following (rebase and merge staging onto master for prod release):

1. git rebase -i master
2. git checkout master && git merge --no-ff staging
3. git checkout staging

   - Here is where I get the your branch has diverged message. Every single time I rebase and merge I get it. This has never happened to me before so I'm worried my git history may be in a mess or something?

Message:

```
Switched to branch 'staging'
Your branch and 'origin/staging' have diverged,
and have 20 and 19 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

If I then run `git pull` & `git status` it will say:

```
On branch staging
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/staging' by 21 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How is my local branch ahead of origin by 21 commits?! All I did was merge staging (which had 1 hotfix branch with 1 commit) into master?!

Note that this will happen if I rebase and merge development onto staging. It's like it carries over for each release step?!

My setup is as follows: development -> staging (release to staging server) -> production (release to production server)

At the moment what I have todo is `reset --hard origin/<branch>` when this occurs

Comment: What happens if you run `git status` on staging right after rebasing staging on master? My guess is it's showing you this because your local copy of staging has been rebased on master while your remote staging branch has not. If there were any commits made on master then both staging branches have diverged hence the message.

Comment: Those counts show you how many commits are *reachable* from your branch and not from theirs. If `master` itself is "ahead of" `staging` (as in has 20 commits on it that `staging` does not) and you add one merge, you add 21 commits: the 20, plus the merge.